# elasticsearch terms on bool field not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query that returns always null :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": {
        "nested": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "old": false
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "path": "jobOffers"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's what match all returns :

```
{
    "hits": [{
                "_index": "dev",
                "_type": "recruitment",
                "_id": "202837r",
                "_score": 1,
                "_routing": "202837",
                "_parent": "202837",
                "_source": {
                    "score": 1,
                    "jobOffers": [{
                        "jobId": "jksncdjkqsnhcjkqs",
                        "jobCompany": "company 1",
                        "jobTitle": "Comptable",
                        "old": false
                    }],
                    "totalCount": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "dev",
                "_type": "recruitment",
                "_id": "202838r",
                "_score": 1,
                "_routing": "202838",
                "_parent": "202838",
                "_source": {
                    "score": 1,
                    "jobOffers": [{
                            "jobId": "wxjkckjwxhcmlazdkklqjkcn",
                            "jobCompany": "company 2",
                            "jobTitle": "Commercial",
                            "old": false
                        },
                        {
                            "jobId": "lxjkckazdwxctrzadjkoo",
                            "jobCompany": "company 2",
                            "jobTitle": "Chargé de développement commercial",
                            "old": false
                        }
                    ],
                    "totalCount": 2
                },
                ...
            }
```

I made sure I'am querying the right index and the right type. Is this behavior normal? How can I make it return the expected result?

Comment: In your query, you need to write `jobOffers.old` instead of just `old`

Comment: Yep that works, thanks. You can make an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, you need to write `jobOffers.old` instead of just `old`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": {
        "nested": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "jobOffers.old": false       <--- modify this
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "path": "jobOffers"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```